# Location of a Point class

Tags: java

Can someone please enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong? I have the errors listed below the code. I am just getting my feet wet with Java so, please be nice in your response.

```
//The Point class definition
public class Point 
    {
    private int x;
    private int y;

   // Constructors
    public Point() 
    {
      x = 0;
      y = 0;
   }

    public Point(int newX, int newY) 
    {
      x = newX;
      y = newY;
    }
  // Getters and Setters
    public int getX() 
    {
      return x;
    }

     public int getY() 
    {
      return y;
    }

    public void setX(int newX) 
    {
      x = newX;
    }

    public void setY(int newY) 
    {
      y = newY;
    }

   public double distance(Point another) //takes one parameter of Point type and returns a double
    {
      double xDiff = x - another.x;
      double yDiff = y - another.y;
      return Math.sqrt(xDiff*xDiff + yDiff*yDiff);
    }

    public void translate(int dx, int dy)
//takes two int parameters for values used to translate,returns a new point with a new location (do not update current location) point. 
    {                     
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
    }  

    public void setXY(int newX, int newY) //updates the location of the point all at one time.
    {
      x = newX;
      y = newY;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
      return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }

}
```

Error when I run the driver:

```
 PointDriver.java:24: error: method distance in class Point cannot
 be applied to given types;
        pt3 = pt2.distance(3, -10);
                 ^    required: Point    found: int,int    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 
 PointDriver.java:31: error: method distance in class Point cannot be
 applied to given types;
        pt1 = pt1.distance(4, -2);
                 ^    required: Point
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: Since the errors occur in `PointDriver` maybe showing that code would be beneficial? Were you supposed to define a method `public double distance( int x, int y ){ }`?

Comment: You have defined the distance() method to take a Point parameter, but are trying to pass in two integers.

Comment: I changed the return to double but still received the same error.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: The error message is not telling you about the return value, it's telling you about the argument types:  "method `distance` in class `Point` cannot be applied to given types. ... required: Point    found: int,int"  It's saying you called `distance(x, y)` where x and y are ints.  But that's not how you declared it.  You declared it to take one Point.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is happening because you are passing two integers to a method that is expecting a `Point`. But without seeing your code that is actually referenced in the error, it's hard to know for sure.

I'm going to guess that your line:

```
pt3 = pt2.distance(3, -10);
```

should probably look like this:

```
pt3 = pt2.distance(new Point(3, -10));
```

or possibly like this:

```
Point p4 = new Point(3,-10);
pt3 = pt2.distance(pt4);
```

Or maybe you should write a new method in `Point`:

```
public double distance(int x, int y) 
{
    Point p = new Point(x,y);
    return this.distance(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Distance nethod need a Point not a separates coordinates.
Use:

```
pt3 = pt2.distance(new Point(3, -10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass distance a Point object not 2 integers.  Try something like this:

```
pt2.distance(new Point(3, -10));
```

That is what you are probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you didn't have called the method distance with a Point. It will work, when you do it like this:

```
 Point t = new Point(4, -2);
 pt1.distance(t);
```

The other problem lies in

`pt1 = pt1.distance(4, -2)`, because the pt1 is a point, but the returning value is a double.

You could do that like this:

```
double p1 = pt1.distance(4, -2)
```